# Is this SQL query guaranteed to join correctly?

Tags: sql, inner-join

This is a pretty basic question, but for some reason, I can't reassure myself. I have a sql query that I want to ensure is acting as I expect.

`question_records` has a foreign key for both `enrollments` and `questions`

```
SELECT `question_records`.* FROM `question_records` 
  INNER JOIN `enrollments` ON `enrollments`.`id` = `question_records`.`enrollment_id` 
  INNER JOIN `questions` ON `questions`.`id` = `question_records`.`question_id` 
  WHERE (enrollments.id IN (10,20) 
         AND questions.id IN (500,600) 
         AND question_records.id not in (3000,4000))
```

What I want to make sure is that I will not get a question record with, for instance, an enrollment_id of 11 and a question_id of 500. In other words, does this inner join treat this where clause on a record-by record basis? More importantly, does it *always* treat it so? (I can come up with a test example, but want to make sure I'm not missing a case.

Edit: Additional narrative for clarity:

It is possible that there is a `question_record` in the database with an `enrollment_id` of 11 and a `question_id` of 500. If this query were not searching conditions on a record-by-record basis, it would match on the `question_id` of 500 and return the record. This is not the behavior that I want. I only want records for which **both** the `enrollment_id` *and* the `question_id` are matched for a given record. The answers I've gotten cover this condition.

Comment: For anyone else to answer your question, you have to explain very clearly what you expect from the query to return.

Comment: For the specific part, no, the query will never return a row with "an enrollment_id of 11 and a question_id of 500". The only combinations of `(enrollment_id, question_id)` are `(10,500)`, `(10,600)`, `(20,500)` and `(20,600)` for this query.

Comment: @ypercube Hurgh, good catch. I got `IN` and `BETWEEN` confused.

Comment: @millimoose Perhaps the OP has the same confusion. Otherwise the `11` question does not make much sense.

Comment: @ypercube that's what I needed. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something subtle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mental model for evaluating this query is that:

1. You grab all rows from `question_records`, `enrollments`, and `questions`.
2. You create a cartesian product of these three row sets. (Match everything with everything at first.)
3. The `INNER JOIN` filters the rows of the cartesian product this based on whether the `ON` conditions are true.
4. Then you filter this based on the final `WHERE` condition.
5. Select the desired columns to form the final result.

(Obviously the database will optimise that to something else entirely.)

So, if a row matches the `INNER JOIN..ON` conditions, but does not match the `WHERE` one, it won't appear in the final result. It has to match all the conditions.

This might be easier to understand when you know that your `INNER JOIN` is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT qr.* FROM question_records qr
                 enrollments      e
                 questions        q
  WHERE e.id = qr.enrollment_id
    AND q.id = qr.question_id
    -- your original WHERE condition
    AND enrollments.id IN (10,20) 
    AND questions.id IN (500,600) 
    AND question_records.id not in (3000,4000))
```

(This form matches the mental model I outlined better.)

Comment: This is excellent. Taking the time to understand what the INNER JOIN is equivalent to is the step I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is really whether the SQL optimizer will push the conditions from the WHERE clause into the JOINs and do the filtering as an intermediate result on each table before performing the join then the answer is that there is no such *guarantee* but in simple cases like this any half way decent optimizer would.